# reveal form did not show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Im a web hosting student so Im not an expert in web hosting and i really need some help. I have a form that will reveal additional information when choosing "company". it work just fine when run it in a compiler but when i open using browser it did not work.

[here is the result when opening in browser][1]

```js
<!---JS--->



$('select[name=type]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '2') {
        $('#companyinfo').show();
    } else {
        $('#companyinfo').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
<!--CSS-->


#companyinfo {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML CODE-->

<html>
<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

<link href="style/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/form.css"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<table width="576" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="clear">  
<tr>
    
<td><p style="font-size:16px; color:#518411;"></p><a name="top" id="top"></a>All fields marked with <FONT COLOR="#FF0000">*</FONT> are required.
</td>
</tr>
 
<tr>
                
<td height="20" >&nbsp;</td>
          
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>PERSONAL INFORMATION</td></tr> 
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>  
  
<tr>
    
<td>
                    
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      
                       
<tr>
                      
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
                      
</tr>

<tr>                       
<td height="22" class="bodyArial">E-mail Address<font color="#FF0000"> *</font></td>
                        
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
                        
<td valign="top"><input name="email" type="text" class="content-text-Darkgrey-BOX-long" id="email" size="30" />
                            
<strong class="bodyArial"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></strong></td>
                      
</tr>
                       

<tr>
                        
<td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                      
</tr>
            
<tr>
<td>Enrolment Type</td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td><select name="type" required>
        <option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
        <option value="1">Individual</option>
        <option value="2">Company</option>
        </select></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>        
</table><br />

<table id="companyinfo">
<tr><td>COMPANY INFORMATION</td></tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Company Name<font color="#FF0000"> *</font></td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td><label id="company1"><input name="companyname" type="text"  size="30" /></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>
 
<tr>
<td>Date of Incorporation</td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td valign="top"><label id="company2"><input name="companyday" type="text" class="content-text-Darkgrey-BOX-long" size="5" /> 
&nbsp;/&nbsp; <input name="companymonth" type="text" class="content-text-Darkgrey-BOX-long" size="5" /> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <input name="companyyear" type="text" class="content-text-Darkgrey-BOX-long" size="5" />         <strong class="bodyArial"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></strong> </label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>                      
<td height="22" valign="top">Address</td>                       
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>   <td height="22" valign="top"><label id="company3"><textarea name="companyaddress" cols="38" rows="5"   class="content-text-Darkgrey-BOX-long" id="Address"></textarea></label></td>                    
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Contact Person<font color="#FF0000"> *</font></td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td><label id="company4"><input name="contactperson" type="text"  size="30" /></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Position</td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td><label id="company5"><input name="position" type="text"  size="30" /></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Tel No.<font color="#FF0000"> *</font></td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td><label id="company6"><input name="companytel" type="text"  size="30" /></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Mobile No.</td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td><label id="company7"><input name="companymobile" type="text"  size="30" /></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email Address<font color="#FF0000"> *</font></td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td><label id="company8"><input name="companymail" type="text"  size="30" /></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Websites</td>
<td valign="top" class="bodyArial"><div align="center" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong> : </strong></div></td>
<td><label id="company9"><input name="companysite" type="text"  size="30" /></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>
</table>




<br />

<p>COURSE TYPES (Please Tick)</p>
<table>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="course" value="course1"></td>
<td>&emsp;</td>
<td><b>Learner Heavy Machinery Operator Program (Level 1)</b><br> Duration: 8 Weeks<br> Pre-requisite: 18 years old, Valid Driving License<br> Vocational Training: Classroom + Practice </td>
</tr>
</table>

<br />
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="103" align="left">
<input name="submitbtn" type="image" onclick="return submit_form();" src="images/btn-submit.gif" alt="Submit"  border="0" style="margin-right:20px;" /></td>
<td width="387"><a href="javascript:;"><img src="images/btn-reset.gif" alt="Reset"  border="0" onclick="document.forms['form_contact'].reset()" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have fiddle for this code?
And your js folder contains jquery file?

Comment: I've made the edit to add jquery to the fiddle!

Comment: I see your table with id="companyinfo". The issue may simply be that you are not including jQuery properly if your error is that $ is undefined. Make sure you are pointing to the correct jQuery file and that it is where it is expected.

Comment: okey i got it i dont have any jQuery file. is there any template how to create JQuery file that are suitable for my code?

Comment: Add this! <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: i have try it. it work fine from compiler but when opening it from browser it still won't show. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have 2 jquery min files in your script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

1. Keep only 1 jquery min file, preferably the first one.
2. Make sure your jQuery file is under `<html><head>` tag,or just before `</body>` tag

The "$" is not defined error occurs mostly when;

- You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded.
- You have really old version of jQuery
- Your JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
- You have multiple versions of jQuery in your file; and there is conflicts of $ variable; for example: using prototypejs and jquery. In such cases; use:

  jQuery.noConflict();

Also, run your javascript code in a block like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```